# How do you 25 point bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/18267/14848)... has a 25 point bounty?  What's up with that?  Is that a thing?

If it is a thing, how do I do it?  Bountying seems to start at 50 if I approach it the normal way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a 50-rep bounty that was reduced by half due to not being awarded in time.

> #### [When does a bounty expire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)
>
> […]
>
> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.